# for loop (i, j) -- obtain i=1 and j=1 then i=2 and j=2, etc

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two lists of files that I would like to combine into a single file through a custom function that I've created.

In the following example, the custom function can be replaced by this line `print(paste(i, j))`. I am using print/paste to illustrate my point.

```
l1 <- c("file1a", "file1b")
l2 <- c("file2a", "file2b")

for(i in seq(along = l1)) {
for(j in seq(along = l2)) {
print(paste(i, j))
}
}

# [1] "1 1"
# [1] "1 2"
# [1] "2 1"
# [1] "2 2"
```

How can I get

```
# "1" "1" file1a and file2a where a = 1

# "2" "2" file1b and file2b where b = 2
```

only?

Therefore, ignore

```
# "1 2" file1a and file2b where a = 1 and b = 2

# "2 1" file1b and file2a where a = 1 and b = 2
```

Comment: `i = j`. Use one loop only, not two.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph    Can you give an example of how to use one loop in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(l1)) print(paste(i, i))`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph  Thank you for suggestion, that code worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
for (pair in Map(c,1:4,1:4)) print(paste(pair[1],pair[2]))
#[1] "1 1"
#[1] "2 2"
#[1] "3 3"
#[1] "4 4"
```

Another example:

```
for (pair in Map(c,l1,l2)) print(paste(pair[1],pair[2]))
#[1] "file1a file2a"
#[1] "file1b file2b"
```

You can also just do:

```
Map(paste,l1,l2)
#$file1a
#[1] "file1a file2a"
#
#$file1b
#[1] "file1b file2b"
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I am going to use the last example. Thank you.